# Points on two of the sides of a triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

Point $D$ lies on side $AB$ of triangle $ABC$ and point $E$ lies on line $AC$ such that $BD=CE$. If $M$ is the intersection of $ED$ and $BC$, show that $DM:ME=AC:AB$.

[image]

I wasn't able to do anything without constructing something in addition to what we have in the problem. I don't know if this is needed, but lets $DP\parallel BC, P\in AC$. Now $$\dfrac{DM}{ME}=\dfrac{PC}{CE},$$ so we can try to show that $$\dfrac{PC}{CE}=\dfrac{AC}{AB}$$ which is the ultimate goal. I tried to use $\triangle APD\sim \triangle ACB$ and $\triangle PDE\sim \triangle CME$, but it didn't work. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying Menelaus Theorem
$$\frac{BD}{AB}\times \frac{AC}{EC}\times \frac{EM}{DM} = 1 $$

Since $CE=BD$

$$\frac{AC}{AB}\times \frac{EM}{DM} = 1 $$

OR

Using Proportionally Theorem, $DP\parallel BC$
$$\frac{DB}{AB}=\frac{PC}{AC},\text {then}, \frac{DB}{PC}=\frac{AB}{AC} $$
and

$$\frac{EC}{AC}=\frac{EM}{MD},\text {then}, \frac{EC}{PC}=\frac{EM}{DM} $$

Since $CE=BD$

$$\frac{AC}{AB}=\frac{DM}{EM} $$

Comment: Thank you for the response! Isn't the Menelaus Theorem stating that $$\dfrac{EA}{EC}\times\dfrac{CM}{MB}\times\dfrac{BD}{DA}=1?$$ I don't understand your first equality. It isn't the theorem in its basic form.

Comment: @Medi, your writing is correct but there are different versions to write it.

Comment: Where can I read about them

Comment: https://brilliant.org/wiki/menelaus-theorem/#:~:text=Menelaus'%20theorem%20relates%20ratios%20obtained,that%20three%20points%20are%20collinear.

Comment: I have already read the topic on that site. There isn't anything about your version of the theorem.

Comment: @Medi, applying some algebraic operations it is easy to get one from another.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127187/discussion-between-lion-heart-and-medi).

Comment: @Medi To apply Menelaus, you identify a triangle and a transversal, then set up the equation. LionHeart is using triangle $ADE$ with transversal $BMC$. You are using triangle $ACB$ with transversal $EMD$.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved via ratios of areas.

To simplify our discussion, I let AC = (a). And (b), (c), (x) and (y) are similarly defined as shown. Furhtter I let $[\triangle ADM] = 1$ square unit.

[image]

Then, $[\triangle DMB] = [\dfrac cb]$ square units.

Similarly, $[\triangle AME] = [\dfrac yx]$; and $[\triangle MBE] = [\dfrac {cy}{bx}]$.

From $\dfrac {[\triangle AMB]}{a}= \dfrac {[\triangle MBE]}{c}$, we have

$\dfrac {1 + \dfrac {c}{b}}{a} = \dfrac {\dfrac {cy}{bx}}{c}$ and the required result follows after simplicication.